# Is there any shortcut to add the lambda/func arrow operator => in Visual Stuido 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

It's really a simple thing, ReSharper did it for me when I was writing a lambda expression, but I stopped using ReSharper and would like to know if there is any way to auto-complete a lambda or func operation with the `=>`

```
builder.HasKey(m => m.Id);
```

Following the @Sajeetharan tip, I created this snippet, but I would like to use it in a more simple way, I need to press tab 2 times and after that press enter, I'm not sure if it is efficient at all, almost returning to resharper for these little things

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>lambda</Title>
            <Shortcut>lambda</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for lambda</Description>
            <Author>Nestorzin</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                  <ID>Name</ID>
                  <Default>r</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$Name$ => $Name$$end$]]>
            </Code>         
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: You can create and  use Code Snippet in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is **`NO`** shortcut available. Certainly you can define one code snippet and insert,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>lambda</Title>
            <Shortcut>lambda</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for lambda statement</Description>
            <Author>Bestorzin</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[(() =>
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    });]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

And save it on

```
C:\YourName\Documents\Visual Studio 201?\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm going to test it right now x)

Comment: more or less, I would like to just press tab to use the snippet, I need to press tab twice and once enter, did some modifications and posted on the question – Nestorzin 20 mins ago